# How can I split a packed Ed25519 public signing key into its X and Y coordinates?

Tags: elliptic-curves, keys

I'm using the Curve25519 code (from http://www.dlbeer.co.nz/oss/c25519.html), and trying to convert from a public signing key (Edwards form) to a public key-exchange key (Montgomery form). There's test code that does that, but it seems to extract the Y coordinate from the *secret* key, and if I had the secret key I wouldn't need to do this.

I'm a software developer, not a mathematician. I don't see how to go from a packed Ed25519 public key to the unpacked X and Y coordinates required for the conversion.

**How can I split a packed Ed25519 public signing key into its X and Y coordinates?**

I'm asking for the mathematical explanation and/or references to the functions in that package that will split the packed Ed25519 key into X and Y coordinates.

For reference, I've tried the `upp` function to unpack the public key, and the `ed25519_try_unpack` function. Both give the same (incorrect) value.

Comment: Why do you care about the second coordinate when you want to convert to a montgomery DH key, which is typically x-only?

Comment: Hello, @CodesInChaos. I've looked at your implementation as well, but couldn't figure out what I needed to do from it. Anyway, the comment on the `morph25519_e2m` function is "Convert an Edwards Y to a Montgomery X (Edwards X is not used)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tldr: **Public and private points have the same EdDSA serialization formats** (notwithstanding external wrappers *around the serialized points* such as PEM, PKCS#12, OpenSSH, *etc.*). Therefore, that library's `ed25519_try_unpack` should be able to be "ab"-used as a decompression algorithm for private points with no issue (especially if the keys' length in octets is the same).

---

The format in question is a **slight variant on** the "compressed" format of [EC serialization from `Standards for Efficient Cryptography 1`, §2.3.3](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.2.3.3).

Compared to the above-linked standard EC point serialization, "Bernstein serialization":

- Truncates $x$ (the **first coordinate**) during compression, rather than $y$.
- Encodes the truncated coordinate **trivially** during compression. (This contrasts starkly with SEC 1, which maps the truncated coordinate through $0 \mapsto 2 ; 1 \mapsto 3$ before encoding.)
- Encodes $y$ into **1 fewer bits** than would be required to encode ${p}-{1}$; this saves a bit *for free* given that its highest bit will always be zero.
- The concatenation of ${Y} \mathbin\Vert {X}$ is done **bitwise**, without padding each encoded bitstring along octet boundaries. (This allows the previous optimization to save an octet in the case of `Ed25519`.)
- It **lacks the header byte**; compressed format is *assumed*. The encoded length is *always* $\lceil{{({{\lceil{\text{log2}{({p})}}\rceil}+{1}})}\div 8}\rceil$. Strings of length $0$ and ${\lceil{{\text{log2}{({p})}} \div 8}\rceil} \times {2}$ are *defined* as invalid encodings.
  This has the following consequences, both intentional security features for the context of EdDSA:

  - $\mathcal{O}$ (the point-at-infinity) has no representation.
  - Since compressed format is forced, points in $\mathbb{Z}_p^2 \setminus E$ (that is, "points-*off*-the-curve") have no representation; any attempt to encode such a value will yield the representation of a point in $E$ (*technically, in $E \setminus \mathcal{O}$.)

---

> I'm a software developer, not a mathematician. I don't see how to go from a packed Ed25519 public key to the unpacked X and Y coordinates required for the conversion.

The problem is that the "compressed" serialization **simply doesn't contain** the whole $x$-coordinate, only its $\text{mod 2}$ parity:

> The public key `A` is an octet encoding of the point $sB$, as follows:
>
> First, encode the $y$ coordinate as a little-endian string of 32 octets. To form the encoding of the point $sB$, copy the least significant bit of the $x$ coordinate to the most significant bit of the final octet. (The most significant bit of the final octet is always $0$.) The result is the public key.

Thankfully, $x$ *can* be recovered given $y$, the least significant bit of $x$, and knowledge of the curve the point lies on. The [demo/illustrative Python script](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/python/ed25519.py) published with the original Ed25519 paper includes a function `xrecover` that shows how to make this recovery. The authors of IETF RFC 8032, however, recommend a [marginally more complicated process](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8032#section-5.1.3) (slightly adapted for the format here):

> First, interpret the string as an integer in little-endian representation. Bit 255 of this number is the least significant bit of the $x$ coordinate; denote this value $x_0$. The $y$ coordinate is recovered simply by clearing this bit. If the resulting value is $\geq p$, decoding fails.
>
> To recover the $x$ coordinate, the curve equation implies $x^2 = {({y^2 - 1})}/{({d y^2 + 1})}\text{ mod }p$. The denominator is always non-zero mod $p$. Let $u = y^2 - 1$ and $v = d y^2 + 1$. To compute the square root of $u/v$, the first step is to compute the candidate root $\tilde{x} = {({u/v})}\text{^}{({{({p+3})}/8})}$.  This can be done with the following trick, using a single modular exponentiation for both the inversion of $v$ and the square root: $$\tilde{x} = {({u/v})}^{{({p+3})}/8} = u v^3 {({u v^7})}^{{({p-5})}/8} \text{ mod } p$$
>
> Again, there are three cases:
>
> 1. If $v \tilde{x}^2 = u \text{ mod } p$, $\tilde{x}$ is a square root.
> 2. If $v \tilde{x}^2 = -u \text{ mod } p$, set $\tilde{x} := 2^{({{({p-1})}/4})}x$, which is a square root.
> 3. Otherwise, no square root exists modulo $p$, and decoding fails.
>
> Finally, use the $x_0$ bit to select the right square root: If $\tilde{x} = 0$ and $x_0 = 1$, decoding fails. If $x_0 = \tilde{x} \text{ mod } 2$,set $x := \tilde{x}$; otherwise, set $x := p - \tilde{x}$. Return the decoded point $(x,y)$.

---

Worked raw example (since I assume you're using a different library after all these years) would be something like this, with code borrowed from the above RFC document:

```
# constants
P = 2 ** 255 - 19  # Finite field modulus
D = -121665 * pow(121666, -1, P)  # Twisted Edwards curve constant
SQRT_NEG1 = pow(2, (P-1)//4, P)  # Square root of P-1 in the field

def encode_publickey(scaled_B):
    "Serialize point to Bernstein compressed format"
    x, y = scaled_B
    A = bytearray(int.to_bytes(y, 32, 'little'))
    assert (A[-1] & 0x80) == 0
    A[-1] &= (0x80 * bool(x & 1))
    return bytes(A)

def decode_publickey(A):
    "Deserialize point from Bernstein compressed format"
    A = bytearray(A)
    x_0 = int(bool(A[-1] & 0x80))
    A[-1] &= ~(0x80)
    y = int.from_bytes(A, 'little')
    x = _recover_x(y, x_0)
    return x, y

def _recover_x(y, x_0):
    if y >= P:
        raise ValueError
    x2 = ((y*y-1) * pow(D*y*y+1, -1, P)) % P
    if x2 == 0:
        if x_0 != 0:
            raise ValueError
        return 0
    x = pow(x2, (P+3)//8, P)
    if x**2 % P != x2:
        x = x * SQRT_NEG1 % P
        if x**2 % P != x2:
            raise ValueError
    if (x & 1) != x_0:
        x = (-x) % P
    assert (1 + D * x**2 * y**2 + x**2 - y**2) % P == 0  # on curve
    return x
```

Comment: Question for actual mathematicians: is this recoverability a property of points on *all* Edwards curves, only points on *twisted* Edwards curves, a totally different subset of elliptic curves, all elliptic curves, or was it specially engineered as part of Ed25519's selection?

Comment: Yes, this recovery is generally possible for elliptic curves.  You're really just solving for the other coordinate using the curve equation, which is just a quadratic or cubic equation.  Finding square roots and cube roots in a finite field have known simple methods.

Comment: I don't think that this statement is true: "$\mathcal{O}$ (the point-at-infinity) has no representation.".  The byte string 01,00,00,...,00 decodes to x=0 y=1, which is Ed25519's infinity.

Comment: @Myria When I try to import [that key](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEIAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA), I don't get that point: `Crypto.PublicKey.ECC.import_key('-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEIAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----')` seems to decode to x=0x3b4d073c80188b09594f9e0d6ad03a5e615e62b799660f795905c62b20b55a93, y=0x7cd43b685d06dfe696d6731b4d04b9ad95f08808291c959572dd1ddc0715ccce

Comment: Ed25519 private keys are random 32 bytes that are hashed using SHA-512, then are used as the scalar for point-multiplying by the base point.  It's encoded points that can represent $\mathcal{O}$ as a 01 byte followed by 00 bytes.  Try using a public key instead of a private key; Ed25519 public keys are encoded points.